# Integração entre Spring MVC e JPA

Tags: jpa, spring

estou tentando integrar o `Spring` com `JPA` porém até o momento não tive sucesso nessa configuração. Umas das duvidas é se consigo configurar o banco através do `spring-context.xml`. Segue o erro que no momento estou tentando resolver. Server JavaEE `glassfish3`.

#### Erro

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The persistence-context-ref-name [br.com.central.dao.DefaultDaoImpl/entityManager] in module [central] resolves to a persistence unit called [centralPU] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.
```

#### persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

 <persistence-unit name="centralPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

   <!-- entidade mapeada -->
   <class>br.com.central.bean.Cidade</class>

    <properties>
        <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

        <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties> 

 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

#### spring-context.xml

```
<!--  ***** JPA CONFIGURATION  ***** -->

<!-- LocalEnityManagerFactoryBean para criar o EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="centralPU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JpaTransactionManager to manager JPA transactions -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/central" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="connect123" />
</bean>

<!-- Instrui o Spring a realizar gerenciamento @Transactional automático nas classes anotadas -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Realizar injeção de recursos de acordo com a especificação JPA (@PersistenceContext, @PersistenceUnit). -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Realizar a conversão de exceções nas classes @Repository (das exceções nativas como JPA PersistenceExceptions to Spring's DataAccessException). --> 
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!--  ***** JPA CONFIGURATION  ***** -->
```

#### Dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class DefaultDaoImpl<T> implements DefaultDao<T>{

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema criando um `dataSorce` no domain do meu Server(GlassFish) e referenciando no `persistence.xml`

Ficou assim:

#### spring-context.xml

```
<!--  ***** JPA CONFIGURATION  ***** -->

<!-- LocalEnityManagerFactoryBean para criar o EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JpaTransactionManager to manager JPA transactions -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Instrui o Spring a realizar gerenciamento @Transactional automático nas classes anotadas -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Realizar injeção de recursos de acordo com a especificação JPA (@PersistenceContext, @PersistenceUnit). -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Realizar a conversão de exceções nas classes @Repository (das exceções nativas como JPA PersistenceExceptions to Spring's DataAccessException). --> 
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!--  ***** JPA CONFIGURATION  ***** -->
```

#### persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="centralPU" transaction-type="JTA">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

   <jta-data-source>jdbc/CentralDS</jta-data-source>
```

Aqui o tutorial utilizado de como criar [UM DATASOURCE MYSQL NO GLASSFISH](https://luizgustavoss.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/criando-um-datasource-mysql-no-glassfish/)

> **Obs**: Caso sejá usado o server GlassFish, adicionar a Lib do mysql
>   nessa pasta `glassfish\domains\seu_domain\lib\ext`

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro está acontecendo porque no seu arquivo persistence.xml, você informou o atributo *transaction-type* como "RESOURCE_LOCAL", sendo que deve ser "JTA". Somente mudando essa configuração você poderá injetar o EntityManager através da annotation @PersistenceContext, que é como a especificação JPA diz. Quanto ao restante da configuração eu não sei dizer se está correto, porque eu uso spring-boot e isso é mais abstrato.

Comment: Sabe me dizer se eu configuro o dataSource direto no domain do servidor que estou usando ou consigo referenciar ele no spring-context?